# MuleESB - Change Global Elements values at runtime for outbound connector

Tags: mule

I tried to use the Webservice consumer connector as outbound Endpoint to consume the soap services and tried to set username and passwords dynamically. but I can't set values in this way. It is not parsing the MEL expression. How can I do ? Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting the outboundProperties upstream in the flow? Are you sure you are not trying to use inboundProperties passed in from the Workday connector?  This example works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:ws="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws" xmlns:cluster="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/cluster"
    xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws/current/mule-ws.xsd">

    <ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer" service="TicketServiceService" port="TicketServicePort" serviceAddress="http://training-u.cloudhub.io/essentials/delta" wsdlLocation="http://mu.mulesoft-training.com/essentials/delta?wsdl" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <flow name="Copy_of_mydomain1-app-oneFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/soap" doc:name="Copy_of_HTTP"/>
        <set-property propertyName="workday_userid" value="WORKDAY_ID" doc:name="Copy_of_Property"/>
        <set-property propertyName="workday_password" value="WORKDAY-PASSWORD" doc:name="Copy_of_Property"/>
        <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" operation="listAllFlights" doc:name="Copy_of_Web Service Consumer"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Copy_of_Logger"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Add Dataweave before to webservice consumer and put below code in dataweave. It's working.

%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
%namespace wsse http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd
%namespace wsu http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd
---
wsse#Security: {
wsse#UsernameToken @(Id: 'UsernameToken-18BC1F80151A19D55F14976049846641'): {
wsse#Username: 'john',
wsse#Password @(Type: 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText'): 'doe',
wsse#Nonce @(EncodingType: 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary'): 'EQDDem3KeXpbud4mJKpLVw==',
wsu#Created: '2017-06-16T09:23:04.662Z'
}
}
}

You can then add the the add property transformer before the webservice consumer (i had added the above as payload, so mapping from payload):

<set-property propertyName="soap.Security" value="#[message.payload]" doc:name="Property"/>

Also, remove the security settings from global web service consumer settings.
```